# ACRA - silently send crash reports without any crash dialog

Tags: android, acra

I don't want to show any toast, notification and any dialog, want to send the crash reports silently without any crash dialog but when I applied below code, I am getting default crash dialog box. Any body have any idea how to get rid of crash dialog when mode is silent.

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW", 
        forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false,
         mode=ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT)
```

Comment: In order to cut the crash dialog you can refer to the answer to this question: [Catching error and user information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486627/catching-error-and-user-information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, ACRA doesn't rely on the system dialog when gathering reports.
Your reports should be sent even if the user clicks REPORT or not in the system dialog.
I guess "silent" means that no ACRA dialog is created.

For my apps, I just used the instructions on their wiki (http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup?tm=6#Setting-up_your_project) and everything worked. I still get crash reports on the market developer console but I get a much better idea about how an app is behaving from ACRA.

If you want to hide the default crash dialog entirely, I guess the only solution is to fix the crashes :)