# Catching error and user information

Tags: android

I have a problem because my application runs in the background and sometimes an error occurs that closes it. How to catch an error in any activity or service in order to play a sound and add info on the notification bar?

Comment: no code and/or logcat??

Comment: Try catch made for such situations.wrap your codes in try{} block then handle error on catch Block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can use uncaughtExceptionHandler interface for this.

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler{

Utils utils ;
Context context;
private final String LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";

public ExceptionHandler(Context con) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context = con;
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    arg1.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
    StringBuilder errorReport = new StringBuilder();
    errorReport.append("************ CAUSE OF ERROR ************\n\n");
    errorReport.append(stackTrace.toString());

    errorReport.append("\n************ DEVICE INFORMATION ***********\n");
    errorReport.append("Brand: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.BRAND);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Device: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.DEVICE);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Model: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.MODEL);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Id: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.ID);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Product: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.PRODUCT);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("\n************ FIRMWARE ************\n");
    errorReport.append("SDK: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Release: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    errorReport.append("Incremental: ");
    errorReport.append(Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
    errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);


    //after this you can do whatever you want , like i start an activity and show error log there


 Intent i = new Intent(context,ExceptionActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("exception",errorReport.toString());
        context.startActivity(i);


        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);





    }
    }
```

and add this line

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
```

in every activity(where uncaught exception can raise)

Answer (score 0):

Use Uncaught exception Handler in Oncreate Method

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Uncaught Exception "+ex);
                            //Habdle your exception here. 

                System.exit(2);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
            }
        });
```